# Why don't open the debugger ndb in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

my packege.json

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
    "debug": "ndb server.js"
  }, ...
```

npm **ndb** is global now.

when run `npm run debug` but don't open the debugger **ndb**. What is the problem or any trick?

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem with my Linux(arch), it was because of visual studio code blocking the same files when it's open.

try to run with it after closing vscode or other editor, because it could be blocking some files to read with ndb.